# Identify location of specific individual(s) in ggplot geom_density facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 10 graphs produced using `geom_density`/`facet_grid`. Five of these have the same individual. Is it possible to indicate in the graph where the individual is for each facet? I thought of using `geom_abline`, but was ultimately unsuccessful.

Current code:

```
ggplot(data=pheno[!grepl("Series",pheno$SOURCE),],
       aes(x=YIELD.BU.A,group=YEAR)) +
       geom_density(aes(colour=YEAR),size=1.5) +
       scale_colour_hue(l=65) +
       facet_grid(YEAR ~ .)
```

EDIT: I can add a vertical line using `geom_vline` but the lines are added to all facets of the plot instead of their respective years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom of this page tells how to add `geom_vline` to individual facets. The final code I needed to add was `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = YIELD.BU.A, colour = LOC), pheno[pheno$SOURCE==2137,])`